# Extract directory from REQUEST_URI

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, uri

I'm interested in extracting the directory from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. I believe I specifically need to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in case the URL is being `mod_rewrite`'d.

If `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'http://example.com/path/to/resource';`, then I can just use `dirname()` on it and get `http://example.com/path/to`.

If the URI is the directory index page/equivalent, but a query string or hash is appended to it, then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` might be something like `'http://example.com/path/?query'` or `http://example.com/path/#hash`. In this case, `dirname()` works as well -- both of those resolve to `http://example.com/path`.

If, however, the URI has no query string or hash, `pathname()` strips off the bottom-level directory, e.g. `http://example.com/path/` becomes `http://example.com`. My solution was to simply append a hash symbol to every URI, i.e. `dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'#')`. `dirname('http://example.com/path/'.'#')` yields `http://example.com/path`.

But I don't understand how URIs work, so I don't really know if this is safe.

- If a URI points to a directory, does it *always* end in the character `/`? If I type `http://example.com/path` in my browser, it redirects to `http://example.com/path/`, adding the trailing slash. Will this *always* happen, though?
- Do query strings and hashes *always* get URL-encoded? For example, I can type `http://example.com/path/?query=a/b/c` in my browser and it gets interpreted as `http://example.com/path/?query=a%2Bb%2Bc`. But if that conversion didn't happen, then `pathname()` would return `http://example.com/path/?query=a/b`, which would be bad.
- Can URIs have `\`s or are directories always separated with `/`?